# Magento 2 : What is typeResolver in GraphQL?

Tags: magento2, graphql

I am working on a custom module in which I've implemented graphql. One of the key in response contains different fields. For example, in the below json response the **dynamic_fields** content will depend on **item_type** and will be different.

```
"response" : {
    "items": {
        "item_id" : 1,
        "item_type" : "custom1"
        "dynamic_fields": {
            "custom_field1" : "data1"
            "custom_field2" : "data2"
        },
        "item_id" : 2,
        "item_type" : "custom2"
        "dynamic_fields": {
            "custom_field3" : "data3"
            "custom_field4" : "data4"
        },

    }
}
```

Can it be implemented using **typeResolver**? How to use typeResolver with **TypeResolverInterface**? Can it be used for dynamic types with **inline fragmens**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TypeResolver helps to decide which type a concrete value belongs to. This is needed for Interface.
For example imagine you have an Interface called ***DashboardOutputInterface*** which resolves back to a series of classes called ***BannerSlider***, ***CategorySlider*** and ***ProductSlider***. The type resolver is responsible for examining a runtime object and deciding what GraphqlObjectType should be used to represent it, and hence what data fetchers and fields will be invoked.

> CompanyName/ModuleName/etc/schema.graphqls

```
type Query {
    dashboard : [DashboardOutputInterface] @resolver( class: "CompanyName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\Dashboard")
}
interface DashboardOutputInterface @typeResolver(class: "CompanyName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\CustomTypeResolverComposite") {
    block_id: Int @doc(description: "Block Id")
    block_type: String @doc(description: "Block Type")
    position: Int @doc(description: "Position")
}
type BannerSlider implements DashboardOutputInterface {
    id: Int
    image: String
}
type ProductSlider implements DashboardOutputInterface {
    id: Int
    products: [ProductInterface]
}
type CategorySlider implements DashboardOutputInterface {
    id: Int
    categories: [CategoryInterface]
}
```

> CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Resolver\CustomTypeResolverComposite

```
public function resolveType(array $data) : string
{
    if (isset($data['block_type'])) {
        if ($data['block_type'] == 'category_slider') {
            return 'CategorySlider';
        } elseif ($data['block_type'] == 'product_slider') {
            return 'ProductSlider';
        } elseif ($data['block_type'] == 'banner_slider') {
            return 'BannerSlider';
        }
    }
    throw new GraphQlInputException(
        __('Concrete type for %1 not implemented', ['DashboardOutputInterface'])
    );
}
```

**Your query look like**

```
query getDashboard {
  dashboard {    
    block_id
    block_type    
    position
    __typename
    ...CategorySliderFragement
    ...ProductSliderFragement
    ...BannerSliderFragement
  }
}
fragment CategorySliderFragement on CategorySlider {  
    id
    categories {
        id
        name
    }
}
fragment ProductSliderFragement on ProductSlider {  
    id
    products {
        id
        name
    }
}
fragment BannerSliderFragement on BannerSlider {  
    id
    image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a resolver for any custom type field you declare. Looks here like you may be extending the existing `items` type? Presuming this is either the `items` type defined in the `cart` query (`[CartItemInterface]`) or maybe the `items` type defined in the `products` query (`[ProductInterface]`)?

If either of those assumptions is correct, seems like you may have to add a new type to either `CartItemInterface`/`ProductInterface` and declare a resolver for them within the schema file. More info in regards to this can be found here in dev docs:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/develop/extend-existing-schema.html#extend-the-schema

Comment: Thanks for writing, but I need detailed explanation on it and a code example would be appreciated. I've already gone through the above documentation but not able to implement it practically.

Answer (score 0):

First, all types must be declared in the schema. If the sub-types of dynamic_fields are subject to change (custom_field1,custom_field2 etc) then you might have to declare these as a key/value return type? Where the key is the attribute code and the value is the attribute value

```
type DynamicFieldOutput { 
    key: String 
    value: String 
}
```

Then, you may want to define a resolver on the dynamic_fields field. This resolver will return the key/value output defined above. The resolver must implement `\Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface`. You should be able to access the product model via `$value['model']` in the `resolve` function implemented via the interface.

```
interface ProductInterface {
    dynamic_fields: [DynamicFieldOutput] @resolver (class: "\\Namespace\\Module\\Model\\Resolver\\DynamicFieldResolver")
}

type DynamicFieldOutput {
    key: String
    value: String
}
```